# TypeAheadField rebuilding twice on tap Flutter

Tags: flutter, typeahead

I have this `Widget` on `Build()` method.

```dart
Widget _buildIngredientsAutocompleteTextField() {
print("Check if rebuild");
 return TypeAheadField(
      hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: true,
      hideOnEmpty: true,
      hideOnError: true,
      keepSuggestionsOnSuggestionSelected: false,
      keepSuggestionsOnLoading: false,
      textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
        focusNode: searchFocus,
        controller: searchController,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 30,
          ),
          hintText: "hint this",
        ),
      ),
      suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
        print("Check 1");
        return await getSuggestions(pattern);
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {...

 onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
        setState(() {
        SOMECODE....
        });
      },
    );
```

And added Listner for the keyboard(not sure if this is the reasonn:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onHide: () {
        searchFocus.unfocus();
        searchController.text = "";
      },
    );...
```

Every time I tap this TextField, it builds this Widget twice, open keyboard, close it and reopen it.

What could be the reason?

This is the debug console output:

```
I/flutter ( 2081): Check if rebuild
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2081): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2081): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2081): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2081): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2081): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
I/flutter ( 2081): Check if rebuild
```